# limiting bar_chart (seaborn barplot) labels on axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 4 x 26 = 104 categories in string format

```
a  34
b  53
c  24
...
z  23
aa 345
..
cz 232
```

which I make into a barchart using seaborn barplot. However, I don't want to show all categories on the axis as the overlap and are linear anyway. I tried

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(4))
```

but this just takes a,b, c, d instead of a, aa, ba, ca.

I did not have any luck with the other Locators either. Is there an way (preferably elegant) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using a combination of setyticklabels and set_major_locator

```
    ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_ymajorticklabels()[::26])
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(numticks=4))
```